# How to make .bashrc call dependant on tmux program being installed?

Tags: bash, tmux, bashrc

I have a section in my .bashrc that fires up the tmux program (terminal multiplexor).

However if the tmux program isn't installed (say I'm setting up a new computer) then having this in my .bashrc file stops any terminal window from successfully opening at all.

Of course installing tmux fixes this, but that isn't my problem.

How can I make this conditional so that if tmux **isn't** installed it doesn't crap out / give an error message?

Currently I have:

```
if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
  exec tmux
fi
```

I want something like:

```
if tmux; then
  if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
  fi
fi
```

but that gives me

```
The program 'tmux' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Though it does at least give me a terminal prompt instead of closing the window!   Also if/when tmux is installed this doesn't give any error / cause any issue when opening a new terminal window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the command `type` to see if the executable is present on your box:

```
if [ -n "$(type -P tmux)" ]; then

    ...tmux is installed...

else

    ...tmux isn't installed...

fi
```

I've often used this code snippet to do it:

```
$ [ -n $(type -P tmux) ] && echo "installed" || echo "not installed"
installed
```

I can fake it out using the alternative to `-n` (not empty string), `-z` (empty string).

```
$ [ -z $(type -P tmux) ] && echo "installed" || echo "not installed"
not installed
```

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of this, just posting it for future readers: the syntax cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3 is actually a [common Bash pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3). It's not likely to trip up the flow in this case, however.

Comment: @JosephR. - yes thanks for mentioning that. Thanks for that link, never saw that it before, good stuff.

Comment: Honest question: Wouldn't it be better to check for execution permission with `-x`?

Comment: @rahmu - always good to ask questions. Yes it can be done that way as well. The trouble with that method is it isn't as portable since you'll have to hardcode the path the executable. `[ -x /usr/bin/tmux ]`.

Comment: `[ -x $(which tmux) ]`? The only problem I found with this is that `which` behaves differently on `zsh` if ran against an alias.

Comment: @rahmu - Yeah you didn't say you would continue using `type ..` in your previous comment. Yes it gives you a extra level of check to see if `tmux` has it's executable bit set, it's semantics at this point whether you want to test for `-x` or `-z` or `-n`. Odds are if something is on the path under `/usr/bin` that's it executable.

Comment: You can also check `type`'s exit code: `type -P tmux &> /dev/null && ...`

Answer (score 1):

Or, if all you want to do is decide on which executable to fire off, you can do this:

```
executable=$(type -P tmux)
executable=${executable:-xterm} # For example
exec $executable
```

The expansion `var=${var:-string}` assigns the value "string" to `var` if and only if nothing has been assigned to `var` before.